# Initialize perl array elements if it is not defined or empty

Tags: arrays, perl, initialization

Is there an easy way (other than iterating through each element) to initialize n elements of `@fields` if it is not defined or empty  ?

```
my @fields = '-' x n;
$string    = 'a|b||c';
@fields    = split(/\|/,$string);
```

Comment: Why would you think you need to initialize elements in an array?

Comment: You *can* initialize $n elements of @fields... but as TLP says, why would you want to? You can trust Perl to give you undef if you read from an uninitialised part of the array, you won't get random memory contents.

Comment: @JamesGreen At line 3 in this code, it doesn't matter what he initialized: The entire array is overwritten anyway.

Comment: Well, yeah, that too :-)

Comment: I agree folks. I wanted array to be of fixed size n at the end of operation.

Comment: @Jean Why do you think that the size of the array matters? What do you think this is, C?

Comment: @Jean, Yeah, except you replace the entire contents of the array in the third line, so your initialisation is gone.

Comment: Also, `'-' x $n` would create the string `------...`, not add elements to the array. You'd need this syntax for that `('-') x $n`.

Answer (score 1):

To create an array of *n* elements, you should rather use

```
my @fields = ('-') x $n;
```

Note the dollar sign and the parentheses.

I do not understand what you meant by the following two lines of the code. If you want `$fields[2]` to contain `-` after splitting, you can fix the string before splitting:

```
my $string =  'a|b||c';
$string    =~ s/\|(?=\|)/|-/g;
my @fields =  split /\|/, $string;
```

Or use `map` after it:

```
my $string = 'a|b||c';
my @fields = map length $_ ? $_ : '-', split /\|/, $string;
```

Comment: `defined $_ ? $_ : '-'` can also be written as `$_ // '-'`

Comment: split never returns undef, unless there are capturing parentheses in the split regex that end up not being used as part of the match (e.g. `split /(x)?/, "ab"` returning "a",undef,"b")

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you may want to be initializing all fields not provided by the split?  If so, you can do this:

```
my @fields = ( split(/\|/, $string), ('-') x $n )[0..$n-1];
```

or this:

```
my @fields = split /\|/, $string;
@fields[ @fields..$n ] = ('-') x ($n-$#fields);
```

or this:

```
my @fields = split /\|/, $string;
$_ = '-' for @fields[ @fields..$n ];
```